# Point wise convergence does not imply convergence in $\mathcal{L}^1$

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the measure space $([0, 1], \mathbb{B}([0, 1]), \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of real-valued functions defined on the above space by $f_n = n \cdot 1_{(0, \frac{1}{n})}$.

> Show that while $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f = 0$,
> $\int_{[0,1]} f_n d\lambda$
> does not converge to $\int_{[0,1]} f d\lambda$.
> Define $g = \sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f_n|$. Thus $g : [0, 1] \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$.
>
> Show directly (Do not use Dominated Convergence theorem)
> that $g$ is not integrable.

---

**My try**

First, we compute $\int_{[0,1]} f_n d\lambda$. We have

$$
\int_{[0,1]} f_n d\lambda 
= \int_{[0,1]} n \cdot 1_{(0, \frac{1}{n})} d\lambda 
=
n \cdot \lambda((0, \frac{1}{n})) 
=
n \cdot \frac{1}{n} 
=
1.
$$

Then I use the definition of $g$ to write the following:

$g = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|f_n|$

$
\int_{[0,1]} gd\lambda = \int_{[0,1]} \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|f_n|d\lambda
$

---

**My questions**

I do not know how to relate the above integral to the integral of $f$. Also, I do not know how to calculate the integral of $g$. Additionally, I do not get why non-integrability of $g$ helps to show the argument.

Comment: You're just being asked to do an example. Compute $g(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$. Then compute its integral (and deduce it's not integrable). What is $g(0.27)$?

Comment: @Jamie Radcliffe: Is $g(x)=n$ for $[0,1]$? I think that is where I am stuck. Also, I am not sure where the limit should be $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{[0,1]}f_nd\lambda \neq \int_{[0,1]}fd\lambda$?

Comment: @Jamie Radcliffe: Can I say for all $x \in (0,1)$ let $n=\lceil \frac{1}{x}-1 \rceil$, the $x\in (0, \frac{1}{\lceil \frac{1}{x}-1\rceil})$? Then I can say $\int_0^1 \lceil \frac{1}{x}-1 \rceil dx\leq \int_0^1 (\frac{1}{x})dx$ which does not exits.

Comment: $$\forall x\in(0,1)\quad g(x)=\left\lceil \frac{1}{x}-1\right\rceil,$$
$$\int_0^1g\ge\int_0^1\frac{dx}x-1=+\infty-1=+\infty.$$

Comment: @Anne Bauval: We show that the upper bound blows up, how can we relate it to $\int_{[0,1]}fd \lambda$? Also, what can I say for the case where $x=0$?

Comment: You are *not* asked to "relate it to $\int_{[0,1]}fd \lambda$" (another way to prove that $\int_{[0,1]}gd \lambda=+\infty$ would be to use the DCT but you are forbiden to). What is your problem with $x=0?$

Comment: We are suppose to show $\int_{[0,1]}f_nd\lambda\neq \int_{[0,1]}f d\lambda$. I do not know what the role of $g$ is here? Also, I showed $x \in (0,1)$ not including $x=0$.